# Return all elements of an ArrayList, not print them

Tags: java

```
public double getAllElementsInCollection(ArrayList<Double> nameofCollection){

      double result = 0.0;
      for(Double nameofDouble : nameofCollection){
        result = nameofDouble;
      }
      return  result;       
}
```

I'm trying to write a method that returns all elements of the `ArrayList` passed it but i'm just getting that last was that was insert in the array. how can I accomplish this task? I have been trying to do this since yesterday. i have noticed that  if i do a `System.out.println(nameofDouble);` that would actually print all elements.. but i don't want to print them. I want to returns all the content inside of passed `ArrayList`.

Comment: Well by very nature an ArrayList is probably going to contain more than one of them.
When you say "return" everything, what do you mean? Because your method is only returning a single double.

Comment: Just do: `nameOfCollection.toArray(new Double[nameOfCollection.size()]);` It will give you an array of `Double` values found in the list.

Comment: How do you expect this code to return all the elements contained by that `ArrayList`? The element to be returned in this case is the last one from the `ArrayList` (after the loop finishes).

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: In which form to you want the method `getAllElementsInCollection` to return all elements? The return type of your method is `double` . You can't return all elements of the `ArrayList` in this way. You need to change your return type to some other type like `Double[]` or `ArrayList<Double>` or whatever..!!

Comment: To me it sounds like he's trying to just print everything in one call possibly?

Comment: @user1535963, result is of type double not list.

Comment: @Kevin that's is exactly what i'm trying to do

Comment: @user1535963: How would this differ from just returning `nameOfCollection` itself directly?

Comment: This question can't be answered because the OP doesn't even know what he's asking for...

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make sense... do you want to turn ArrayList into double[]?

Simply call:

```
public Double[] getAllElementsInCollection(ArrayList<Double> nameofCollection){

    return  nameofCollection.toArray(new Double[nameofCollection.size()]);

}
```

Comment: im just a beginer here just doing some test.. i was just trying to write a method where i passed in an arraylist and it should return me all the values inside of such arraylist. the code i made was using a double for example.. but i'm not sure.. thats why i posted it

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of two things:

Firstly:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

...

Double[] elements = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
```

Or, if you want to use the method:

```
public double[] getAllElementsInCollection(ArrayList<Double> list){
    double[] elements = new double[list.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return elements;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got it all wrong. First of all the return type of your method is double, which indicates you can just return a single double value and not the entire array. Also the variable 'result' will hold only one value within it. So here is the modified version of your code :

```
public List<Double> getAllElementsInCollection(List<Double> nameofCollection){

  List<Double> resultList = new ArrayList<Double>();
  for(Double nameofDouble : nameofCollection){
    // some processing on the elements (if required)
    resultList.add(nameofDouble);
  }
  return  resultList;
```

}

Also, I suggest you to use super classes/interfaces(like List instead of ArrayList) as parameters or return types, because you may not know the actual argument passed to the method(like LinkedList or ArrayList). Read OOP concepts throughly for this. Polymorphism samples : [sample1](http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-guide-to-polymorphism-in-java/) and [sample2](http://www.java-made-easy.com/polymorphism-in-java.html)

Comment: What is the reason of creating the same **new** `List` and returning this new `List`?

Comment: Yeah. this answer makes no sense... you can just return nameOfCollection and be done with it.

Comment: If you are not performing any operation then why do you ned to call the method and return the same List at first place. The reason I had created a new list in the example is, if you want make any manipulations and not want to change the values in the original list. I have added the comment as well in the code itself.

Comment: @Kevin - Returning the same `List` i.e `nameOfCollection` (which is supplied as a parameter to the method) makes no sense at all. Hence, the question itself makes no sense!

Comment: @Lion : I agree with you. This is exactly why I had used another List.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method in following way to return all elements of `ArrayList` in String which can be printed further.

```
public String getAllElementsInCollection(ArrayList<Double> nameofCollection){

      return java.util.Arrays.toString(nameofCollection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, what do you mean with "returns all elements"? The ArrayList has all elements, in which form do you ant to return them?

Looking on your code, do you mean the sum of all elements? Then you have just a little mistake. Your code `result = nameofDouble` just replaces the result, so the last is returned. `result = result + nameofDouble` or `result += nameofDouble` would sum all the elements.